# Webhook not firing consistently for RingCentral Glip posts

Tags: webhooks, ringcentral, glip, ringcentral-webhooks

I have successfully created a Glip bot in the sandbox and registered the corresponding webhooks, following the instructions found here: https://ringcentral-api-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glip_bots/

When testing in the sandbox, I only get a webhook payload about 50% of the time when the bot is spoken to in a conversation.  I would expect to get one every time, since the bot has a subscription for posts, and is a member of that group.  Additionally, if the subscription wasn't working at all, I would expect to get it 0% of the time.  Literally the same text will trigger it once, but not the second time.

I determined that there was nothing wrong with the endpoint by using Postman to simulate webhooks.  Every time I created a simulation, the bot became aware of the post and responded accordingly.  So it isn't the endpoint.  It would appear that RingCentral Glip is not calling the endpoint every time it should.

It could potentially be a sandbox issue but I don't see any documentation that supports that theory.  The specific event that's not firing every time is "/restapi/v1.0/glip/posts".  As I continue to investigate I thought I'd reach out to see if anyone else experienced this issue, or has suggestions on how to debug.

Comment: Please, double check. We found missconfiguration on our side and fixed it.
RingCentral team

Comment: It is working consistently now.  Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: No problem. Do not hesitate to contact me in case of issues.